# Building a slider in OOP (JS and jQuery), having a problem with fadeIn() and fadeOut()

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm currently working to create a slider with jQuery and JavaScript. I managed to make the change of slide working but I cannot find any solution to add a `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` effect working well...

No matter where I put those effects in the code, it doesn't work for me....
I tried to put them in the `changeImage()` function but it doesn't change anything.

I must add that, it's an exercise and I do not have the possibility to use a plugin of any sort.

Here is my code :

```js
$(function(){

    //Current slide
    let i = 0;

    //Slides Objects
    let slide = {
        //Init slide
        init: function(image, title, description) {
            this.image = image;
            this.title = title;
            this.description = description;
        },

        //Return image source
        origin: function() {
            let source = this.image;
            return source;
        },

        //Return image title
        showTitle: function() {
            let headTitle = this.title;
            return headTitle;
        },

        //Return image description
        showDesc: function() {
            let descriptionContent = this.description;
            return descriptionContent;
        }
    };

    // Time Between Switch
    let time = 5000;
         
    // Slides creation
    let slide1 = Object.create(slide);
    slide1.init("image-slider-1.jpg", "Première slide", "Description 1");

    let slide2 = Object.create(slide);
    slide2.init("image-slider-2.jpg", "Deuxième slide", "Description 2");

    let slide3 = Object.create(slide);
    slide3.init("image-slider-3.jpg", "Troisième slide", "Description 3");

    let slide4 = Object.create(slide);
    slide4.init("image-slider-4.jpg", "Quatrième slide", "Description 4");

    //Adding slides to Array
    let slides = [];
    slides.push(slide1);
    slides.push(slide2);
    slides.push(slide3);
    slides.push(slide4);

    let animateSlides= setInterval(changeImage, time);

    $('.slides').on('mouseout', function(){
        animateSlides;
    });

    $('.slides').on('mouseover', function(){
        clearInterval(animateSlides);
    })

    

    function changeImage() {
        
        $('#slideImage').attr('src', slides[i].origin());
        $('#slideTitle').text(slides[i].showTitle());
        $('#slideDesc').text(slides[i].showDesc());

        //If current image number is not the last, pass to the next
        if (i < (slides.length - 1)) {
            i++;
            
        //Else, go to the beginning of the slider
        } else {
            i=0;
        }

    }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Carte de location de vélos</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <section class="slider">
            <div class="slides">
                <img id="slideImage" src="" alt="">
                <div class="content">
                    <h2 id="slideTitle"></h2>
                    <p id="slideDesc"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="bike-booking container">
    
        </section>
    </div>

</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you seen examples for [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/#entry-examples) and [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/#entry-examples)? You should create element for each slide and hide all of them but one, and repeat fadeOut on visible element, fadeIn next element

Comment: ...what's POO? 

Comment: @zerr00ne Oups, I'm french so POO is Object Oriented Programming ahahah so funny I didn't pay attention

Comment: @barbsan Yes I saw them but isn't there any other way to use fadeIn and fadeOut using the logic of my js code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `setInterval`'s callback - this will `fadeOut` current slide, then change it's content and `fadeIn`.

```
setInterval(function(){
   $('.slides').fadeOut("slow", function(){
      changeImage()
      $('.slides').fadeIn("slow");
    })
}, time);
```

Demo:

```js
$(function() {

  //Current slide
  let i = 0;

  //Slides Objects
  let slide = {
    //Init slide
    init: function(image, title, description) {
      this.image = image;
      this.title = title;
      this.description = description;
    },

    //Return image source
    origin: function() {
      let source = this.image;
      return source;
    },

    //Return image title
    showTitle: function() {
      let headTitle = this.title;
      return headTitle;
    },

    //Return image description
    showDesc: function() {
      let descriptionContent = this.description;
      return descriptionContent;
    }
  };

  // Time Between Switch
  let time = 5000;

  // Slides creation
  let slide1 = Object.create(slide);
  slide1.init("image-slider-1.jpg", "Première slide", "Description 1");

  let slide2 = Object.create(slide);
  slide2.init("image-slider-2.jpg", "Deuxième slide", "Description 2");

  let slide3 = Object.create(slide);
  slide3.init("image-slider-3.jpg", "Troisième slide", "Description 3");

  let slide4 = Object.create(slide);
  slide4.init("image-slider-4.jpg", "Quatrième slide", "Description 4");

  //Adding slides to Array
  let slides = [];
  slides.push(slide1);
  slides.push(slide2);
  slides.push(slide3);
  slides.push(slide4);

  changeImage();
  $('.slides').fadeIn("slow");
  let animateSlides = startAnimatingSlides(time)


  $('.slides').on('mouseout', function() {
    animateSlides = startAnimatingSlides(time);
  });

  $('.slides').on('mouseover', function() {
    clearInterval(animateSlides);
  })

  function startAnimatingSlides(interval) {
    return setInterval(function() {
      $('.slides').fadeOut("slow", function() {
        changeImage()
        $('.slides').fadeIn("slow");
      })
    }, interval);
  }

  function changeImage() {

    $('#slideImage').attr('src', slides[i].origin());
    $('#slideTitle').text(slides[i].showTitle());
    $('#slideDesc').text(slides[i].showDesc());

    //If current image number is not the last, pass to the next
    if (i < (slides.length - 1)) {
      i++;

      //Else, go to the beginning of the slider
    } else {
      i = 0;
    }



  }

});
```

```css
.slides {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
  <section class="slider">
    <div class="slides">
      <img id="slideImage" src="" alt="">
      <div class="content">
        <h2 id="slideTitle"></h2>
        <p id="slideDesc"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="bike-booking container">

  </section>
</div>
```

PS. I've fixed restarting slideshow on `mouseover` - you need to call `setInterval` again, `animateSlides` is just a handle to clear that interval.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Now I just have to find how to make the first slide appears as soon as the page loads. But that's already a great step ahead for me thanks to your answer :)

Comment: just set `display: none` on slide element and call `changeImage(); $('.slides').fadeIn("slow");` somewhere (I've updated it in demo)

Comment: It works indeed but I don't understand the logic of those modifications...

Comment: All of them or only the last one?

Comment: No, just the last one sorry. ^^'

Comment: `setInterval`'s callback is called every 5s in your example, but first call occures not at the time you set it, but after given interval. So, you need to call the same code as in callback. When the page loads, there's no need to call `fadeOut`, you can make your element invisible (`display: none`) so it's enough to `changeImage()` and make it visible using `fadeIn`

Comment: Ok, so to put it in a nutshell I need to call the function a first time outside the interval I've set in order to make the first slide appears directly ? :)